# Microsoft Graph Sharepoint search inconsistent results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to implement a feature in our app to allow users to search for files in their Sharepoint & OneDrive accounts, as they see in Office365.

I am having trouble understanding why I am not seeing expected results from search API requests.

When I make a search request like this, I get 1 result as expected:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{my-site -id}/drive/root/search(q='brisbane')
```

However, when I search like this, there are no results:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='brisbane')
```

If I modify the query for `/me/drive/search`, I do see results from OneDrive, but not from SharePoint.

According to the [Microsoft Graph docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search), `/me/drive/search` should search for 'Items a user can access'.

Is this the expected result? Is there any way to search all the current users' Sharepoint sites? Or do I have to ask the user to configure the sites they would like to search, then search each of them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. You need to read below the ["Searching for items a user can access"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search#searching-for-items-a-user-can-access) heading to understand what this means:

> In addition to searching for items within a drive, your app can search more broadly to **include items shared with the current user**. To broaden the search scope, use the search method on the Drive resource.

When you're searching `/me/drive/` you are searching that user's OneDrive for files they have uploaded themselves or have been explicitly shared with them. Files that live within a SharePoint library that a user happens to have access to are quite different than files "shared" with that user.